# Why is the reputation to nominate one's self as moderator only 300?

Tags: discussion, election

It seems a bit low to me. 300 reputation doesn't make a person an active member at all. I suppose that person could be doing a lot of stuff behind the scenes, but even at that, I feel that a person has to be a part of a community to lead it, and 300 just isn't enough of a commitment.

I think 1000 should be a minimal level, if not higher.

Comment: I'm not as concerned with low rep as I am with low rep and long membership.  If someone's been on different SE sites and just joined a site and gained 300 in a week, before nominations, and they maintain a reasonable level of activity on all their sites, that's not nearly as much a concern for me as someone who's been on for, say, six months, and is earning something like 50 points a month and not asking questions or giving good answers.

Comment: Agreed, Established User should be the minimum level.  Even excellent contributors to other SE sites are unlikely to have a very good feel for a site with only 300 rep, IMO, to counter TangoOversway's point.

Comment: Completely agree with @MatthewRead. A moderator doesn't need to be able to answer questions, they need to be able to assist the site in running smoothly. Maybe they have 300 rep, but tons of edits and are active on meta.

Comment: I can say from my experience as a pro-tem moderator on Graphic Design, it is possible to moderate a site for which you are not intimately involved, but it does make it much more difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can say this, as an active user, and a moderator on 2 sites now.

It is entirely possible to be a moderator on a site and not be very active on it. I have been a moderator at Graphic Design for a year now. During this period of time, I have asked/answered about 5 questions, gaining maybe a few hundred reputation. I would like to think I've done a fair job at moderation. But only fair really.

To be a moderator, one needs to know the site inside and out. They need to know what is on topic, what is off topic, what is general reference, and what is a good question. They need to participate in meta, chat, at least to read and take part in policy decisions, but they will be better off if they are actively contributing to the site.

I have recently been voted in as moderator of a site that I am quite active in, and have been active for a year, namely Science Fiction and Fantasy. It has made a huge difference being active in the site, and knowing what I need to do to help make it better.

While I can and will continue on as a Graphic Design moderator for so long as I need to, I feel like I would be better off if I cared more about the community.

So, I would suggest raising the limit to at least 2000, and quite possibly 3000. At least a 3000 user will have had to think about closing posts, which is one of the most basic things a moderator needs to do.